# Error in Inserting Values into PostgreSQL table through php

Tags: php, jquery, postgresql

I'm trying to insert received values into postgresql table using php. I can't figure out why this statement doesn't work

```
  $query = "INSERT INTO user_info (name, emailAddress, phoneNumber, jobDesc) VALUES ('" . $name . "," . $emailAddr . "," . $phoneNumber . "," . $jobDesc ."')";
```

I get this error:

```
Query failed: ERROR:  column &quot;emailaddress&quot; of relation &quot;user_info&quot; does not exist
```

However, I tried this one:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO user_info VALUES ('" . $name . "," . $emailAddr . "," . $phoneNumber . "," . $jobDesc ."')";
```

It works, but it inserts all values into first column!

I'm not sure what I'm missing here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing a whole host of single quotes in your `VALUES` list...

```
$query = "INSERT INTO user_info (name, emailAddress, phoneNumber, jobDesc) VALUES ('" . $name . "','" . $emailAddr . "','" . $phoneNumber . "','" . $jobDesc ."')";
```

Comment: Is `emailAddress` spelled correctly or even exists? It seems to be taking issue with that column.

Comment: Yes, and its type is character varying. would that be the issue by any chance?

Comment: I removed the email value then the same error appears with the next value "phoneNumber"

Comment: Which SQL are you sending. You said you tried one with the columns and one without the columns? Are you doing this one: `$query = "INSERT INTO user_info (name, emailAddress, phoneNumber, jobDesc) VALUES ('" . $name . "','" . $emailAddr . "','" . $phoneNumber . "','" . $jobDesc ."')";`?

Comment: Also, what is special about the `name` column? It seems to be working. Is it set up differently?

Comment: Yes, the SQL you wrote, and I created the user_info table with the same exact column properties

Comment: Are the other column types maybe not the correct kind for what kind of text/data you are trying to store in them? I only ask because I am familiar with `MySQL` not `PostgreSQL` to the error is foreign to me a bit. I just find it odd that it will allow the `name` column to work but not the others.

Comment: Okay, I left this statement and used the other one, fixed the error with single quotes as you suggested and it works. Many thanks!